Why are the heights of these 2 Material 3 Buttons different?
Im trying to have a dynamic "loading button" that is meant to have a CircularProgressIndicator inside it, and I have the code for scaling it correctly.
However the default height of the button is the problem, and I have therefore stripped away unnecessary Compose code below.
Can anyone help me figure out why the sizes of these 2 buttons are different?
Top button gets height 40.dp
Bottom button gets height 48.dp
(I know I can make the bottom button be 40.dp by using LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement which at least would result in similar sizes, however a bit small)
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                ) {
                    Column {
                        var buttonSize by remember { mutableStateOf(DpSize.Zero) }
                        val density = LocalDensity.current

                        Button(onClick = { }) { Text(text = "I have height of 40 dp") }

                        Button(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .then(if (buttonSize != DpSize.Zero) Modifier.size(buttonSize) else Modifier)
                                .onSizeChanged { newSize ->
                                    if (buttonSize == DpSize.Zero) {
                                        buttonSize = with(density) {
                                            newSize
                                                .toSize()
                                                .toDpSize()
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                            onClick = {},
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "I have height of 48 dp")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

